# What are the hardware algorithmic implementations of arithmetic operations on Intel's Core 2 architecture?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, hardware, intel

As of the time of this writing, Intel's currently in the middle of its Core 2 processor line with the Skylake microarchitecture. I'm interested in the hardware algorithms that are currently being hard-wired into Intel processor instructions in the interest of calculating true time complexity of an algorithm by connecting it to the hardware implementation details. Does anyone know of the implementation algorithms or of white papers that explain such things, or perhaps benchmarks of basic instructions that suggest certain time complexities?

Wikipedia has a list of computational algorithms that may or may not be used but definitely exist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations

Comment: Operations on any kind of processor are almost universally O(1).  You could argue that the IA32 string-processing instructions are O(n) in the length of the data they process, but it would be more accurate to view them as O(1) instructions that conditionally repeat themselves.

Comment: @comingstorm Since most instructions have a fixed width, it can be assumed that they're all O(1). However, most algorithms for arithmetic are *not* constant, and so even though the `n` is constant, the constant time still depends on the algorithmic complexity of the hardware implementation.

Comment: @comingstorm I removed time complexity from the question header, as I am looking for more specific information than just a coefficient-stripped order function.

Comment: I would look for hardware/VLSI design texts/papers to learn this stuff.  Because hardware is inherently parallel, it has a very different flavor from most software algorithms -- space complexity is the total area of the logic needed, while time complexity is the latency from input to output...

Comment: You're looking for things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter for single-cycle-latency rotates by a variable count, right?  What do you mean "... in the interest of calculating true time complexity of an algorithm by connecting it to the hardware implementation details"?  Are you trying to work out which instructions use more power (more heat, less battery life)?  If you just want to know which instructions are fast, see http://agner.org/optimize/ for instruction tables and the CPU microarchitecture guides to make sense of them.